# How to declare angular 1.x material theme color in scss

Tags: angularjs, sass, angularjs-material, material-design

How to declare angular 1.x material theme colors to scss properties. For Example i want theme primary color for background property;

Example:

> .sampleclass{ background: theme-primary-color;}

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$theme-primary-color: 'red';
.sampleclass{ background: $theme-primary-color;}
```

You can look more details about sass [here](http://sass-lang.com/guide).

Comment: Thank you.But I want angular material theme primary, accent color.